# Duplicate fields in Elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Does anyone know if an dhow this can be done in Elementor.

I want to create a price estimator and I need a simple duplication of form fields in the ADD PRODUCT section then simply get a sum of all added products. The Add Product button should simply duplicate the form select fields in the first row then display a sum based on the number of form fields that were selected.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqLW0.jpg)

Total sum. Did not try anything yet aside from displaying total.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.